# Search with Angular2 using 2 subject observables

Tags: angular, merge, rxjs, observable

I have 2 Subject observables that I would like to merge once each subject's debounce time is complete. I'd like to send the 2 input strings of each subject to a service and then merge the results and display it to the user.

So far, I have the following code below:

```
export class SearchComponent{
     private _results = Observable<any>();
     private _search1Field = new Subject<any>();
     private _search2Field = new Subject<any>();

     //following the example from the angular2 heroes app, I have replicated how i will watch one input observable and get results
     //  ngOnInit(){
     //   this._search1Field
     //     .debounceTime(500)
     //     .distinctUntilChanged()
     //     .switchMap(term => {
     //       if(term){
     //         return this.searchForStuff(term);
     //       } else {
     //         return [];
     //       }
     //     })
     //     .subscribe(results => {
     //       this._results = results;
     //     })
     //  }

     //this is the actual approach i am trying to take for both merge
     ngOnInit(){
       let firstSearch = this._search1Field.debounceTime(500).distinctUntilChanged();
       let secondSearch = this._search2Field.debounceTime(500).distinctUntilChanged();
       let concurrent = 2;
       let combinedSearch = Observable.merge(firstSearch,secondSearch, concurrent);
       combinedSearch
         .mergeMap(test=> {
           if(test){
              console.log('searched for ', test);
              // send search with strings from each observable
             return this.searchForStuff(test.firstParam, test.secondParam);
            } else {
              console.log('return nothing');
              return [];
            }
         })
         .subscribe(result => {
           console.log(`Result is ${result}`);
         })
     }

     searchFromTemplate(search1: string, search2?: string) {
       this._search1Field.next(search1);
       this._search2Field.next(search2);
     }

     searchForStuff(firstInputSearch: string, secondInputSearch?: string): Observable<any> {
       let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
         method: RequestMethod.Post,
         headers: this._headers,
         body: '',
         url: `${this.url}?first=${firstInputSearch}&second=${secondInputSearch}`
       });

       //get params from url search as well

       return this._http.request(searchUrl, requestOptions)
         .map(res=> console.log(`This is res json ${res.json()}`))
         .catch(error=> {
           console.log(`There was an error ${error}`);
           return Observable.throw(error.json());
         });
     }
   }
```

The problem with the second ngOnInit method that I tried returns this error when i enter value into the first input field:

```
EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
    at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:120)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:117)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:100)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.OuterSubscriber.notifyNext (OuterSubscriber.js:19)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
    at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next (distinctUntilChanged.js:72)
    at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
```

I'm still trying to wrap my head around Observables please so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you pass `concurent` to the `merge` method. As far as I know it only accepts Obervables.

Comment: @chrigu I saw that in a tutorial i was reading, apparently, having a concurrent enables the observables to run at the same time concurrently.

Comment: Found it in the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-merge) It looks like it's optional so it shouldn't do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `searchForStuff` method does not return anything as you only log the response and do not pass it on. In the `map` method you need to return a value as `console.log()` only returns undefined which is what you are most likely seeing.

```
searchForStuff(firstInputSearch: string, secondInputSearch?: string): Observable<any> {
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        headers: this._headers,
        body: '',
        url: `${this.url}?first=${firstInputSearch}&second=${secondInputSearch}`
    });

     //get params from url search as well

    return this._http.request(searchUrl, requestOptions)
        .do(res=> console.log(`This is res json ${res.json()}`))
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(error=> {
            console.log(`There was an error ${error}`);
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
    });
}
```